# linux shared c library not shared

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries

I have what I thought was a shared library which appears to not be shared.  The shared integer `soShared` should be 2 in the second process.  Instead I get a value of 1 for both instances of the program.  There are three parts in this example, the shared library header, slc.h:

```
#pragma once
extern volatile int soShared;
```

The shared library itself, slc.c:

```
int soShared = 0;
```

and the program that uses the shared resource:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "slc.h"

int main() {
  int value = 0;
  ++soShared;
  for (;;) {
    if (value != soShared) {
      value = soShared;
      printf("pid=%d, value=%d\n",getpid(),value);
    }
    sleep(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

These are compiled and run twice with

```
gcc -c -fPIC -o slc.o slc.c
gcc -shared -o libslc.so slc.o
gcc -o use_slc use_slc.c libslc.so
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` ./use_slc &
sleep 1
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` ./use_slc &
```

But both output `soShared` values of 1; they are not shared.  This is not what I understand should happen, can (A) someone explain why the second use of libslc.so does not have a value of 2 and (B) how can one make the resource soShared actually shared between the two processes?

Answer (score 2):

You just misunderstand what shared libraries mean. It means that a common on-disk, and in-memory for parts of the library that remain unchanged from their contents on-disk, copy of the library gets used for all programs linked to it. It does not mean that all programs/instances-of-programs using the library share common data. That would be a nightmare for security and general bugginess, and libraries that behaved that way would not serve to stand in for static linking as a conforming C implementation.

Incidentally, DLLs on Win16 did work the way you imagined. That was a big mistake and one of the major changes made in Win32.

Comment: To reiterate what R.. said, .so files loaded at runtime are just code which are put into your .TEXT segment at some displacement. This code is copied into every process at runtime but is not packed into the binary at complie-time.  You want to share the some variable between processes that can be done by shared memory using some synchronization construct.